# Android: using Activity's default animation for Fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-activity, transition

I need to use the Activities default animation in a Fragment replace, but using `android.R.anim` I can't find it.

How can I find the name of it?
Is it possible to use it by default, or would I have to create the animation manually in order to use it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having searched for this exact issue, I've found this resource on the Google forums (oddly not in Android-Developers):

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-porting/c75-7TMgn3A/discussion

Comment: @noloman I haven't implemented my version so if you could post an example that would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, how can you alude to those animations in code in a R.anim.xxxx fashion?

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa Manufacturers could have their own animations, attributes can change, styles are fixed