# Android popBackStack setTransition

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to figure out what is the proper way to play transition animation when `popBacksStack` is called.

Right now I am setting the transition from `ListFragment` to `SettingsFragment` like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, settingsFragment)
    .commit();
```

But how should I play the transition when popping `backstack` (Moving back so that `ListFragment` becomes visible again)?

As I noticed, popping `backstack` is not a `fragmentManager` transaction like replacing a fragment so I cannot call the `setTransition` before making the pop.

I would like to keep the code as simple as possible. No custom animations etc.

**Solution:**
I ques I have got too used to Android Studio being smarted than me. Android studio didn't recognize android.R as resource so I thought there is not such thing, but when I started to type in the full path 'android.R.anim.slide_in_left' Android studio picked it up. So my solution looks like this now:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, settingsFragment)
                    .commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSupportFragmentManager() 
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.popEnter, R.anim.popExit )
    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, settingsFragment)
    .commit();

Comment: That looks like a simple and nice solution, but I don't have any animation content under R.anim... 
Doesn't android provide any default animations? Can I download some default animations using Android SDK Manager or from somewhere else?
Normally I would just make some XML animations or copypaste from stackoverflow but I want to know what is the smart way.

Comment: You should rely on this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692837/how-to-use-default-animations-in-android